# How to Install Microsoft Word Add-in in Windows Svr 2008 R2 64bit with Word 2010 32 bit

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-addins

I developed Microsoft Word Add-In for 32 bit systems which is working fine. Now i want to install the same on Win Svr 2008 R2 Enterprise 64 bit with 32 bit Microsoft Word installed. What changes do i need to do in my project and installer.

Desired Target: Win Svr 2008 R2 64 bit with Word 2010 32 bit

Working/Development/Testing PC: Win 7 32 bit with Word 2010 32 bit

Tried Steps

Changed project and installer target to x64

When i give target location in Application folder [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\Office14\ADDINS\ the Add-In automatically installs in C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Office14\ADDINS\ and registry is also updated as required but when word is started it tries to load Add-In in location C:\ProgramFiles\Office14\ADDINS\ whereas files are placed in x86 ProgramFiles because word too is 32 bit.

note: Setup of server (Win08r2 64 bit with 2010 Word 32 bit) cannot be changed as it is running in production.

please guide how do i solve the issue.

Comment: You should not change anything. You are NOT targeting x64. If word is the x86, so should your add-in.

Answer (score 0):

MS Office is 32-bit, so you must have to build 32-bit Setup and x86 or AnyCPU build for Addin assemblies.

The registry entries should be referenced to use the Target directory of the installation.

Stop all instances of MS-Word (WinWord.exe) and Install Addin.